# In the case @object.variable, can the variable be extrapolated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
extras = {'facebook' => '', 'twitter' => ''}
```

And my User attributes are like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :facebook, :twitter, #...
```

I would like to retrieve the data defined in my extras hash in the following fashion (or a better oen - that is the one that came up to my mind)

```
extras.each do |k,v|
    extras[k] = @user.k
end
```

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with the [`.send(:method)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) or the [`.try(:method)`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Object/try):

```
# with this kind of hash:
extras = {'facebook' => '', 'twitter' => ''}
```

You can do that to gather the user's info:

```
extras.each_key do |key|
  extras[key] = @user.send(key.to_sym)      
end
```

Or with [`.try()`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Object/try), which is safer: it **will not raise an NoMethodError** in case of unknown key sent to user:

```
extras.each_key do |key|
  extras[key] = @user.try(key.to_sym)
end
```

You can do it with a map also:

```
extras.each_key{ |k| extras[k] = @user.send(k.to_sym) }
```

I made a post about this code, you can see it here:
http://rails.co.nf/?p=31

Answer (score 0):

`Object#send` can take a string. Not sure about `try` mentioned by @MrYoshiji

```
extras.each_key { |k| extras[k] = @user.send(k) }
```

Note to read the variable, by method name, you need to have that method created with something like `attr_accessible :facebook, :twitter`